# Is it possible to override C syscall open without LD_PRELOAD?

Tags: c, overriding, system-calls, libc, ld-preload

The source gets printed, but no `open:` or `open64:` gets printed. How to fix this? Thanks!

```cpp
/*
gcc -o emload emload.c -ldl
./emload
*/

// emload.c

#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

typedef int   (*orig_open_func_type)(const char *__file, int flags, ...);
typedef int   (*orig_openat_func_type)(int dirfd, const char *__file, int flags, ...);


int open(const char *__file, int __oflag, ...)
{
    orig_open_func_type orig_func;
    orig_func = (orig_open_func_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open");
    int res = 0;

    if (__oflag & O_CREAT) {
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, __oflag);
        int mode = va_arg(ap, unsigned);
        res = orig_func(__file, __oflag, mode);
        va_end(ap);
    }
    else
        res = orig_func(__file, __oflag);

    printf("open: %d (%s)\n", res, __file);
    return res;
}

int open64(const char *__file, int __oflag, ...)
{
    orig_open_func_type orig_func;
    orig_func = (orig_open_func_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open64");
    int res = 0;

    if (__oflag & O_CREAT) {
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, __oflag);
        int mode = va_arg(ap, unsigned);
        res = orig_func(__file, __oflag, mode);
        va_end(ap);
    }
    else
        res = orig_func(__file, __oflag);

    printf("open64: %d (%s)\n", res, __file);
    return res;
}

int openat(int dirfd, const char *__file, int __oflag, ...)
{
    orig_openat_func_type orig_func = (orig_openat_func_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "openat");
    int res = 0;

    if (__oflag & O_CREAT) {
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, __oflag);
        int mode = va_arg(ap, unsigned);
        res = orig_func(dirfd, __file, __oflag, mode);
        va_end(ap);
    }
    else
        res = orig_func(dirfd, __file, __oflag);

    printf("openat: %d (%s)\n", res, __file);
    return res;
}

char source[2 << 20];

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
    FILE* f = fopen("emload.c", "r");
    fread(source, sizeof(source), 1, f);
    puts(source);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it actually work with `LD_PRELOAD`? glibc seems to use its internal `__open` explicitly inside an internal file opening function, and this gets resolved to `__GI___libc_open`. I don't think you'll be able to override it even with `LD_PRELOAD`, since it's not a call to `open`.

Comment: Just tried, it also does not work :( It seems that it's impossible to override open at the syscall level with this simple trick :( Was it changed only in recent versions of glibc? Because there are plenty of questions / repos online that showcase these sort of overrides - those would be useless if it doesn't even work for a simple `fopen` usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLIBC's `fopen` calls the syscall wrapper directly, without any address resolution, so you're out of luck here. Your other options are:

- Use `ptrace(2)` from a separate process, tracing syscalls via `PTRACE_SYSCALL` requests. This will stop on *any* syscall, not just the ones you need, so may potentially degrade performance.
- Patch the wrapper in memory to a jump to your override. This may make it harder to execute the original code, though, because you'd need to analyze its first several instructions (that you overwrite) to reproduce their effect. Or, you can just reimplement the wrapper completely, avoiding the return to the original version.